# Alphanumerical sorting - paste error - large amount of data

Tags: excel, vba

I've devellopped a quick little code to help me sort a large amount of data on an excel tool, it works perfectly except for one tiny detail ruining all of my work so far.

My table is 500+ columns wide and my algorithm would like to copy and paste two rows at a time (I use fused cells and do not wish to use an alternative to that).
My algorithm then tries to do :

```
    Rows(i & ":" & i + 1).Cut
    Rows(j & ":" & j + 1).Select
    Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
```

i and j being the row index (I try to put row j and j+1 just below row i and i+1

Which tells me that excel cannot do with the current ressources.
I tried to reduce the amount of cells with something like

```
range(cells(i,bc),cells(i+1,ec)).cut
range(cells(j,bc),cells(j+1,ec)).select
Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
```

bc being the first column of my selection and ec the last

But still I have the same problem (selection is between 500 and 510 colums so around 1k cells)

**So here is the question :**

Is there a way to bypass that error and force the cut/paste? (I would like to avoid changing x columns at a time, slowing a process already quite slow)

Or a way to change the index of the row or something alike that I do not know about ?

Thank you for your time and future answers.
PEagle

Comment: what other porgrams you are running at the same time ? how big is your file (size) ? see my comment below

Comment: If you need to sort a sheet with merged cells, it's generally going to be much faster to flatten all the merged cells (either on the sheet or in memory with a custom class), sort, then re-merge the cells that need to be merged. Using cut and paste to manually sort on the worksheet with *any* algorithm is going to be a performance nightmare.

Comment: My file is about 6300KB.

Comment: I am aware that sorting is always much faster with the integrated solutions but in that case undoing the merge and redoing it will not even be possible.
I have a fixed pattern for part of it (first columns) and then it is not necessarily the same (no merged cells on the first row, may be of various size and position on the second one).
Thank you for your time, I still try to find a solution on my side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, my question is now obsolete.

I reorked the file, noticing that the file, for a reason I do not know, included all lines until the end of the sheet (1+ million). I have removed the unnecessary lines (recreated the file) and it now works fine.

sorry for your time loss, thank you for helping me.
See you soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, just too long to put as a comment.

I just ran the code below (with 700 columns of data per row), and it **Cut >> Paste** just fine without errors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFullTwoRows()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

' just for simulation
i = 2
j = 10
Rows(i & ":" & i + 1).Cut
Rows(j & ":" & j + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Comment: Alas, my computer sure is (way) less performing than yours...
doing a manual copy gives me a message that it will take long but does not prevent it.
VBA code however still does the crash after a complete reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i am not yet at comment privilegies, so here is the answer to your comments/answers:

My file is about 6300KB.
For other programs, generaly just the outlook and firefox but computers at work are not very powerful.
Regarding the flatening of my merged cells and then sorting, the problem is then that I need to do sorting but only on even lines.

As it is a file from work I cannot send it on the internet, but to give you an idea, I have 2 lines working together, columns B to F are merged (B8+B9, B10+B11 etc, then C8+C9 etc.) and then I have two rows of data for each of these lines.
Unmerging would cause blank cells to pop and then sorting would mess the whole table.